# htaccess Rewriterule to remove trailing slash

Tags: magento-1.9, onepage-checkout, url-rewrite, htaccess

I ran a page seo and it said I needed to remove the trailing slash because it could cause duplicate content. So I found this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

and added it to the htaccess but now I can't pass the Billing Information step in the onepage checkout.

Is this rule correct? Why can't I pass the Billing step?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not required if you activate the canonical URLs under `System` > `Configuration`. This will prevent Google from indexing the page on different URLs

[image: canonical settings]

Comment: I was also thinking about the other search engines. Use Canonical Link Meta Tag For Categories because each category page is different. I use this:  print_r ($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']); in my meta title tag to display p=2 so I don't get duplicate title tag warnings. I use Canonical for  pages thou. Wonder why removing the slash makes it where magento can't check out?

Comment: It will also work for other search engines. This is basically the way to go and will solve a lot more issues next to slash also regarding layered navigation and pagination.

Comment: @Sander Thank you for your answser. I just want to let you know that it will not work in the case of other page (CMS Page and cart page etc)

Answer (score 2):

This removes trailing slashes and redirects uppercase to lowercase as well

```
# Remove trailing slashes (consider backend)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^GET$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/downloader.*$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.+)/$
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s(.+?)/+[?\s]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301] 

# Eugene: Redirect uppercase to lowercase
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^GET$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} [A-Z]
# need RewriteMap lc int:tolower in VirtualHosts httpd.conf
RewriteRule (.*) /${lc:$1} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: where do you add this code?

Comment: .htaccess (usually in www folder for Apache httpd web server), see the comment about lc function in httpd.conf as well (last line)

Answer (score 1):

You can use below code in your `.htaccess` file.

```
# remove trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s(.+?)/+[?\s]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

I have used this and this is working fine for me.

When you will enable the `Use Canonical Link Meta Tag For Categories` and `Use Canonical Link Meta Tag For Product` in `System > Configuration > Catalog > Search Engine Optimization`. This is right that **slash** will not effect your Seo ranking(Duplicate URL Issue). But, this will work for only `Categories` and `Products`. It will not work for other pages.

Comment: Hi @vikas verma where should we need to add this in .htaccess file please advise?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a more recent rewrite rool that also forces to use https (useful if apache is used behind proxy that handles SSL):

```
# Remove trailing slashes (consider backend)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^GET$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/downloader.*$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.+)/$
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s(.+?)/+[?\s]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]
```