# Magento 1.9 Remove Trailing Slash from Cms page URL

Tags: magento-1.9, cms-pages

> **Duplicate Content Issue**

*Example:* `https://www.example.com/test/`

**expectation:**

```
https://www.example.com/test
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [htaccess Rewriterule to remove trailing slash](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/97296/htaccess-rewriterule-to-remove-trailing-slash)

Comment: By the way, nice point that you have raised. +1 for that

Comment: @ShoaibMunir not duplicate this question, question is remove trailing slash to cms page not category page or product